# Bootstrap Modal goes blank after button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to call a Modal function. When I click to view it, it doesn't render and the page goes blank(white).

This is the code for 
*BootstrapModal* :

```
class BootstrapModal extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            showHide : false
        }
    }

    handleModalShowHide() {
        console.log("hitting");
        this.setState({ showHide: !this.state.showHide })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Button variant="third" id="btn-third" onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}>
                    Send Email
                </Button>
                <Modal show={this.state.showHide}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}>
                    <Modal.Title>Email Chart To User</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Modal.Label>Email address</Modal.Label>
                                 <Modal.Input
                                    type="email"
                                    placeholder="Email"
                                 />
                        </FormGroup>

                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}>
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                        <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}>
                            Send
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>

                </Modal>

            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default BootstrapModal;
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? Any suggestions would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change

```
<FormGroup>
    <Modal.Label>Email address</Modal.Label>
        <Modal.Input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
        />
</FormGroup>
```

To

```
<FormGroup>                           
    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Email Adress:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name"></input>
</FormGroup>
```

After changing this, the Modal successfully rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have not binded the handleModalShowHide() function. You can aviod having to do thst using an arrow function:

```
handleModalShowHide = () => {
    Code here
}
```

Comment: Alternative would be adding `this.handleModalShowHide = this.handleModalShowHide.bind(this)` to the constructor, which is just additional mess

Comment: @Carlos, Thank you for your input. Unfortunately the Modal still returns black.
Aswell as @ Antoni returns the same.

Comment: onClick={this.handleModalShowHide}, can you try passing onclick like this?

Comment: I implemented both suggestion and unfortunately still returns blank. I have isolated the issue. It renders successfully if I comment `Model.Label` through  `Model.Input`. So the issue come from those components.